# htacess hide the redirect from browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've tried all suggestions here and else where but I can't hide the redirect from a `.htacess` rewrite rule. My full .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase         /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^classes/(.+)?$ index.php [L]

#shop
RewriteRule         ^shop/(sector1|sector2|sector3|sector4)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) shop?site=$1&category=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule         ^shop/(sector1|sector2|sector3|sector4)/$                   shop?site=$1 [NC,L]
```

Mose of the advice I've gotten is to remove `[r=301]` but I've never had that flag there. No matter what I try `example.com/shop/sector1` always displays as `example.com/shop?site=sector1` any help appreciated

[edit] I'm running this on localhost as a virtual host. Mac OS 7.5, Apache 2.2.26

[edit] Also from the doc root there are other `.htaccess` files, but none in the 'shop' folder with the above rewrite is supposed to effect.

```
$ find . -name .htaccess
./.htaccess
./assets/images/.htaccess
./cms/.htaccess
./cms/assets/images/.htaccess
./cms/assets/plugins/ckfinder/userfiles/.htaccess
./cms/modules/default_images/.htaccess
./sagepay/VspPHPKit/demo/.htaccess
./sagepay/VspPHPKit/lib/.htaccess
./uploads/.htaccess
./uploads/products/.htaccess
```

Also my directory structure is (notice that my redirect `shop` is an actual folder - could this be part of the issue?):

```
$ tree -d -L 1 ./
./
├── assets
├── classes
├── cms
├── contact
├── foo
├── news
├── page
├── products
├── sagepay
├── sample
├── search
├── services
├── shop
├── snippets
├── uploads
└── widgets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing trailing slash in your rewritten URI after `shop` is the problem since it is a real directory and Apache's `mod_dir` will do a 301 redirect to add trailing slash to make `/shop/` and that will make final URL as: `example.com/shop/?site=sector1`

Also better to change order of your rules and make sure to use `L` flag at the end of each rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /

RewriteRule ^shop/(sector1|sector2|sector3|sector4)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) shop/?site=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/(sector1|sector2|sector3|sector4)/$ shop/?site=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^classes/ index.php [L,NC]
```

Also I suggest you to test your rule in a separate browser.

Comment: no joy with either of those suggestions. I'm really starting to think it must something in my apache conf. Also I'm running this on localhost as a virtualhost

Comment: Do you have other rules in this .htaccess OR any other .htaccess e.g. `/shop/.htaccess`

Comment: I saw your edit, so nothing in .htaccess other than above suggested rules of mine?

Comment: nope thats it. Also everytime it rewrite the network in chrome tools shows `301 moved permanently` I've tried clearing the cache

Comment: Try updated code now. I think missing slash in rewritte URI after `shop` was the problem since it is a real directory.

Comment: your a genious ;) viola cest ca - that was the problem. Needed `shop/?x=y` instead of `shop?x=y`. I'll allow you rewrite your answer before I click the tick ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might sound really dumb but it caught me out many moons ago. Given that your code looks fine to me it leads me wonder...

When I found this happening myself, it turned out that all my `href` attributes were actually the after-redirect address! E.g. double check that your `href` attributes are `example.com/shop/sector1` and not `example.com/shop?site=sector1`.

Otherwise something else might be interfering. Do you have any other code in your htaccess? Any PHP redirecting etc?

Comment: wish it was that simple lol - same issue even when I manually type into the address bar

Comment: Ah well. It was worth a shot!